# wpa_supplicant and SNMP mib parameter

Tags: snmp, openwrt, wpa-supplicant

I have a parameter in wpa_supplicant that i control via SNMP mib. I would like to support real-time changes to this parameter **without losing the Wi-Fi link** , which means i think without restarting the service.

Do you have any ideas ! like adding a command to wpa_cli.